# How to split values of a cell in multiple rows in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following data frame, which was obtained using the code:

```
     df1=df.groupby('id')['x,y'].apply(lambda x: rdp(x.tolist(), 5.0)).reset_index()
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672680/how-to-execute-a-function-on-a-group-of-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

The resultant data frame obtained :

```
      id          x,y
  0   1    [(0, 0), (1, 2)]
  1   2    [(1, 3), (1, 2)]
  2   3    [(2, 5), (4, 6)]
```

Is it possible to get something like this:

```
         id      x,y
     0   1      (0, 0)
     1   1      (1, 2)
     2   2      (1, 3)
     3   2      (1, 2)
     4   3      (2, 5)
     5   3      (4, 6)
```

Here, the list of coordinates obtained as a result in previous df is split into new rows against their respective ids.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  If you are using the `repeat` with `sum` methodology, you notice that the concept originated with my post.  If you want to improve your performance further, you may want to consider using a list comprehension to calculate the lengths as demonstrated in my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1['x,y'].values.tolist(), index=df1['id'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='x,y')
print (df2)

   id     x,y
0   1  (0, 0)
1   1  (1, 2)
2   2  (1, 3)
3   2  (1, 2)
4   3  (2, 5)
5   3  (4, 6)
```

`numpy` solution use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) by `lengths` of values by [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html), `x,y` column is flattenig by [`numpy.ndarray.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html#numpy.ndarray.sum):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df1['id'].values, df1['x,y'].str.len()), 
                   'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()})

print (df2)
   id     x,y
0   1  (0, 0)
0   1  (1, 2)
1   2  (1, 3)
1   2  (1, 2)
2   3  (2, 5)
2   3  (1, 9)
2   3  (4, 6)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [54]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df1['x,y'].values.tolist(), index=df1['id']).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='x,y')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

In [55]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df1['id'].values, df1['x,y'].str.len()), 'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()})
1000 loops, best of 3: 562 µs per loop

#piRSquared solution
In [56]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'id': df1['id'].repeat(df1['x,y'].str.len()), 'x,y': df1['x,y'].sum() })
1000 loops, best of 3: 712 µs per loop
```

Comment: Please can you have a look at this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827104/applying-complex-algorithm-on-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 2):

- Calculating the new `'id'` column

  - We can use pandas `str.len` method to quickly count the number of elements in each element's sub-list.  This is convenient as we can directly pass this result to the `repeat` method of `df1['id']` which will repeat each element by a corresponding amount from the lengths we passed.
- Calculating the new `'x,y'` column

  - typically, I like to use `np.concatenate` to push all the sub-lists together.  However, in this case, the sub-lists are lists of tuples.  `np.concatenate` will not treat these as lists of objects.  So instead, I use the `sum` method and that will use the underlying `sum` method on lists, which will in turn concatenate.

## `pandas`

*if we stick with `pandas` we can keep the code cleaner*
**Use `repeat` with `str.len` and `sum`**

```
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].repeat(df1['x,y'].str.len()),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].sum()
    })

   id     x,y
0   1  (0, 0)
0   1  (1, 2)
1   2  (1, 3)
1   2  (1, 2)
2   3  (2, 5)
2   3  (4, 6)
```

## `numpy`

*we can quicken this approach up by using the underlying numpy arrays and equivalent numpy methods*
**NOTE: this is equivalent logic!**

```
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].values.repeat(df1['x,y'].str.len()),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()
    })
```

We can speed it up even more by skipping the the `str.len` method and calculating the lengths with a list comprehension.

```
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].values.repeat([len(w) for w in df1['x,y'].values.tolist()]),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()
    })
```

## Time Tests

*small data*

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].values.repeat([len(w) for w in df1['x,y'].values.tolist()]),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()
    })
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 µs per loop

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].repeat(df1['x,y'].str.len()),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].sum()
    })
1000 loops, best of 3: 590 µs per loop

%%timeit 
pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df1['id'].values, df1['x,y'].str.len()), 
                   'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()})
​
1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop
```

*larger data*

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1.head(3)] * 100, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].values.repeat([len(w) for w in df1['x,y'].values.tolist()]),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()
    })
1000 loops, best of 3: 579 µs per loop

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame({
        'id': df1['id'].repeat(df1['x,y'].str.len()),
        'x,y': df1['x,y'].sum()
    })
1000 loops, best of 3: 841 µs per loop

%%timeit 
pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df1['id'].values, df1['x,y'].str.len()), 
                   'x,y': df1['x,y'].values.sum()})
​
1000 loops, best of 3: 704 µs per loop
```